# How to convert a positive number to negative in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have this code:

```
set /a A=1 + 2

echo A=%A%
```

the output is `A=3`

How can I convert this into a negative value? (i.e. `-3`)

Comment: Simply multiply with -1 `set /a A*=-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just negate it with the `-` operator

```
set A=2
set /a A = -A
```

That's the standard way in almost every programming language. It should also be more readable and slightly more efficient than multiplying with `-1`

In fact you don't even need `/A` in this case, `set A=-%A%` also works

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiply it with `-1`:

```
set /a A=1 + 2

set /a A=%A%*-1
echo A=%A%
```

Comment: i got better,
`set /a B = %A% - %A% - %A%`